# C program :segmentation fault

Tags: c

Im new to C programing and im getting a segmentation fault somewhere in my code. The program uses a return function to ask a user for the start of how much money they have in their bank account. later I will add code to calculate the interest.Thanks for looking at this for me as im having lots of trouble finding out why im getting this error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int getPV()
   {
    int d;
    int start;
    printf("Start: ");
    scanf("%d", start);
    d = start;
    return d;
   }


int main()
   {
     int pv;
     pv = getPV();
     print("%d",pv);
     return 0;
   }
```

Comment: `scanf("%d", start);` --> `scanf("%d", &start);`. Advice: Turn up compiler warnings and never ignore them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call scanf, you need to pass the `address of the variable` to which you want to store the value.

That means, if you want to store the value in variable `start`, you need to pass the `address of start` to `scanf`.

You can get the address of a variable using the `&` operator. So you need to change you scanf to:

```
scanf("%d", &start);
```

---

You get segmentation fault when using `scanf("%d", start);` because, `start` is an automatic variable and will have a garbage (random) value in it before you assign some value to it. `scanf` will treat this random value as the address to which the user entered value has to be stored. Now when `scanf` tries to store user entered value to this random address location, you get segmentation fault, because in most likelihood your program is not allowed to access that address location.